# API showing another business's data

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using Google Place text search API to get reviews of the business name Dental Care of Chino with below code:

> $gRef =
>   reset(json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Dental%20Care%20of%20Chino%20Hills+91709&sensor=false&key=API_KEY&userIp='
>   . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))->results)->reference;

but its showing me [Chino Hills Dental Group](https://plus.google.com/117453056898428348411/about) business's reviews

After analyze the issue I got clue that it might be coz of same zipcode but I'm still confused as I'm passing name as well so why it takes another business's reviews.

Can anyone help me to figure out what exact issue is and why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are worried about the reference for your business changing. It should be reasonably stable, but here is a query that will return your business as long as you don't move your business location:

```
$gRef = reset(json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=33.982357,-117.733055&rankby=distance&keyword=Dental%20Care%20of%20Chino%20Hills+91709&sensor=false&key=API_KEY&userIp=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))->results)->reference;
```

That said, I'd hard wire your reference, or at least cache it for a week or so.

Comment: Hi Brett, Thanks for you answer. I applied phone number filtration to get the exact result. But your answer is really giving a good hint to get data filter by address.